# This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE for Python DASH

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have the following code running which operates two different dash pages. It has been working fine for almost 6 months then now it begins to fail with the following error. If anyone could assist that would be great.

**This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, dash_table

app = Dash(__name__, use_pages = True)

navbar = dbc.NavbarSimple(
    dbc.DropdownMenu(
        [
            dbc.DropdownMenuItem(page["name"], href=page["path"])
            for page in dash.page_registry.values()
            if page["module"] != "pages,not_found_404"
        ],
        nav = True,
        label = "More Pages"
    ),
    brand = "Metric Reporting",
    color = "primary",
    dark = True,
)
app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [navbar,dash.page_container],
    fluid = True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app.run_server(host = '127.0.0.1',port = '8050', debug = True)
```

Comment: If the code worked siz months ago, you might need to upgrade Dash.

Comment: Just tried that - no luck. I have dash 2.6.2 which I think is the latest

Comment: I tried it without pages, it worked with me. Could you please add the code of other pages to run the entire code?

Comment: thanks @Hamzah - I tested just a random dash graph and found the port server it was working off and changed my script code to that. I change the last line of the code to ' app.run_server(host = '127.0.0.1',port = '57353', debug = True)' and that worked perfectly well. I have no idea why ???